# How do I retrieve all the names of a type's properties as an array?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties

Let's say if I have an `Employee` class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name    { get; set;}
    public string Address { get; set ;
}
```

Now I want to create an array with the `Employee` class' property names, i.e.:

```
string[] employeeArray = { "Name", "Address" };
```

Is there a way to achieve this without hard-coding property names?

Comment: So as per the tags, you know that you need to use reflection.  What research have you done in how to get a list of properties of an object using reflection?  What problems have you had with the solutions you've attempted so far?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this using reflection, specifically with the [`Type.GetProperties` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties.aspx).

Here's two possible solutions; one with LINQ, the other without (in case that you're targeting an earlier version of the framework):

- ```
  // using System.Linq;
  typeof(Employee).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToArray()
  ```
- ```
  // using System;
  Array.ConvertAll(typeof(Employee).GetProperties(), p => p.Name)
  ```

Note that [`Type.GetProperties()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx) will only see public instance properties. If you're also interested in the names of static properties, or non-public properties, you will need to call [a different overload of `GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

```
typeof(Employee).GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
```